# How to insert values in sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My question is how do I store values in sqlite database that i am receiving from web service. I am new here in Android. I need some help. Thanks in advance. I searched for an appropriate answer for days now with no solution at all.

Below `responseStr` is the Object I am receiving as a response from webservice, whose values I would like to store in the database.

```
  SQLiteDB sqlite_obj = new SQLiteDB(UrlActivity.this);

  try{                 
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
    String url = mainObject.getString("url");

    if(url.equals("valid")){

        //JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
        //data.put("data",jsonArray2); 

        //List <NameValuePair> nvps2 = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        //nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", mainObject.toString()));

        try{
        ProgressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(UrlActivity.this,  responseStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        sqlite_obj.open();
        sqlite_obj.deleteAll(); 

        JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray2.put(mainObject);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);
        //sqlite_obj.insert();


        }

        sqlite_obj.close();


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stored in SQLite DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SQLiteException:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Also, below is my SQLiteDB class.

```
public class SQLiteDB {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_USER_ID= "user_id";
public static final String KEY_NUMBER_OF_CHECKIN= "no_of_checkin";
public static final String KEY_STATUS="status";
public static final String KEY_URL="url";


private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQLiteDB";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "databasetable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table databasetable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "user_id integer not null, " +
            "no_of_checkin integer not null, " +
            "status integer not null, " +
            "url text not null );";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public SQLiteDB(Context ctx) {

this.context = ctx;
DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

try {
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS databasetable");
onCreate(db);
}
}

//---open SQLite DB---
public SQLiteDB open() throws SQLException {

db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}

//---close SQLite DB---
public void close() {

DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert data into SQLite DB---
public long insert( 
            Integer user_id, Integer no_of_checkin, Integer status, String url) {

ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(KEY_USER_ID, user_id);
initialValues.put(KEY_NUMBER_OF_CHECKIN, no_of_checkin);
initialValues.put(KEY_STATUS, status);
initialValues.put(KEY_URL, url);


return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---Delete All Data from table in SQLite DB---
public void deleteAll() {

db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}   
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is, as the title indicates, "How to insert values in sqlite?", then please explain what problems you are encountering with your code. For example, are you crashing? If so, what does LogCat tell you?

Comment: My problem is : How to make connection with the database & insert the values I am getting through web service?